# Latching in Google Sheets Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google sheet that displays and saves the current date when a specific text is filled in a specific cell. Afterwards, when this cell is changed to a separate text, the previous date is saved, and the date of the editing is added. This is what I mean:

First, the cells are like this:

```
    |Status    |Date Started|Date Completed
    ----------------------------------------
    |          |            |
```

Afterwards, when I type in "Started":

```
    |Status    |Date Started|Date Completed
    ----------------------------------------
    |Started   |08/02/2021  |
```

After the task is started and completed, I wish to have it displayed as such:

```
|Status    |Date Started|Date Completed
---------------------------------------
|Completed |08/02/2021  |09/02/2021
```

As I'm using the same cell as an input in the script editor to update the date started and date completed, the problem was that once the cell is changed to "Completed", the "Date Started" cell would disappear. Therefore, my initial solution to this was to latch the input "Started" so that once the designated cell is changed to "Started", the "Date Started" cell is latched and does not change. This is the code I wrote for this task. However, it works when I type "Started". When I change it to any other text, the starting date cell disappears.

```
  function Test5(input) {
  var flag;
  if (input=="Started")
  {
    flag=1;
  }
  if (flag == 1)
  {
    return("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

When I typed "Started", this is the outcome:

```
    |Status    |Date Started|Date Completed
    ----------------------------------------
    |Started   |08/02/2021  |
```

After typing "Completed", the "Date Started" cell disappears as follows:

```
    |Status    |Date Started|Date Completed
    ---------------------------------------
    |Completed |            |
```

The above code is the function for the "Started" input. I am still planning to create another function to use for "Completed" input. There is something wrong with my code, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

**Issue:**

- The `if` condition in your code evaluates only for `Started`. If you choose `Completed` then the first `if` evaluates to `false` therefore `flag` does not get a value and as a result the second if evaluates to `false` as well and your function does **not** return anything.

**More suitable solution:**

- I am not sure why you use a regular function for that purpose but also your code is not complete, because we don't see how you set up the value back to the sheet.
- However, a more suitable approach would be to use a simple [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. Save the following code in your script editor and then upon edits (see attached gif) you will get the desired results.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1" // put the name of your sheet
  const ar = e.range;
  const as = ar.getSheet();
  const arow = ar.getRow();
  const acol = ar.getColumn();
  let col;
  if(as.getName()==sheetName && arow>1 && acol==1){  
    if(ar.getValue()=="Started"){
      col = 2; // if "Started" write in column B
    }
    else if(ar.getValue()=="Completed"){
      col = 3; // if "Completed" write in column C
    }
  as.getRange(arow,col).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),
  e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

- You **should not** execute this code manually because you will get an error. The `onEdit` trigger is activated **automatically** when the **user changes the value of a cell**. In this case, the timestamps will be set to column B or C when you edit the value of  a cell in column A (except for the header) with `Started` or `Completed` respectively.
- Also modify `Sheet1` in the code to the name of your sheet and `acol` or `col` values depending on the columns you are working on.

### Illustration:

[image]